# Error while connecting cassandra cluster from java code

Tags: cassandra, google-cloud-platform, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have deployed datastax cassandra cluster in google cloud and able to load the data and query from cqlsh but not able to connect from JAVA code. Getting the following error message.

**Cassandra Version**

```
3.0.7
```

**Error Message**

```
<searchResultResponse><error><errorCode>200</errorCode><errorMessage>All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /104.155.229.139:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces))</errorMessage></error></searchResultResponse>
```

**nodetool status**

```
Datacenter: asia-east1-a

========================

Status=Up/Down

|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving

--  Address     Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack

UN  xx.xxx.x.4  974.53 MB  64           ?       e7974879-647f-460a-ac2e-0828bcefe7cb  asia-east1-a

UN  xx.xxx.x.2  832.5 MB   64           ?       4d152508-d9ea-4fea-89a6-ef3e86b036ac  asia-east1-a

UN  xx.xxx.x.3  942.64 MB  64           ?       de4798b7-2a74-4104-be0b-1ed093183276  asia-east1-a

Datacenter: europe-west1-b

==========================

Status=Up/Down

|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving

--  Address     Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack

UN  xx.xxx.x.4  849.3 MB   64           ?       a9af8255-8f09-4d41-a9a5-5ce769b47cd6  europe-west1-b

UN  xx.xxx.x.2  906.62 MB  64           ?       3389e168-cf8e-4bd2-8947-cbfd42187a64  europe-west1-b

UN  xx.xxx.x.3  945.59 MB  64           ?       c2a561fc-6fa1-440d-8f42-e85a866ed48a  europe-west1-b

Datacenter: us-east1-b
======================

Status=Up/Down

|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving

--  Address     Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack

UN  xx.xxx.x.4  904.41 MB  64           ?       43b49588-841b-4925-bf3f-ab59ca227186  us-east1-b

UN  xx.xxx.x.2  953.32 MB  64           ?       d658b8c8-ee24-4e15-9240-7c4aac92f723  us-east1-b

UN  xx.xxx.x.3  843.16 MB  64           ?       1ee956b8-3823-4324-ac8f-582d312851b3  us-east1-b
```

**Cassandray.yaml from one of the node**

```
cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'

num_tokens: 64



hinted_handoff_enabled: true
max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000 # 3 hours

hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024

max_hints_delivery_threads: 2

hints_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/hints

hints_flush_period_in_ms: 10000

max_hints_file_size_in_mb: 128


batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb: 1024

authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator

authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer

role_manager: com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseRoleManager

roles_validity_in_ms: 2000


permissions_validity_in_ms: 2000


partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner

data_file_directories:
     - /mnt/data

commitlog_directory: /mnt/commitlog

disk_failure_policy: stop

commit_failure_policy: stop

key_cache_size_in_mb:

key_cache_save_period: 14400

row_cache_size_in_mb: 0

row_cache_save_period: 0


counter_cache_size_in_mb:

counter_cache_save_period: 7200


saved_caches_directory: /mnt/saved_caches

commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000

commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32


seed_provider:
    # Addresses of hosts that are deemed contact points. 
    # Cassandra nodes use this list of hosts to find each other and learn
    # the topology of the ring.  You must change this if you are running
    # multiple nodes!
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          # seeds is actually a comma-delimited list of addresses.
          # Ex: "<ip1>,<ip2>,<ip3>"
          - seeds: "10.142.0.4"

concurrent_reads: 32
concurrent_writes: 32
concurrent_counter_writes: 32

concurrent_materialized_view_writes: 32







memtable_allocation_type: heap_buffers



index_summary_capacity_in_mb:

index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes: 60

trickle_fsync: true

trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 10240

storage_port: 7000

ssl_storage_port: 7001

listen_address: 10.140.0.2

broadcast_address: 10.140.0.2



start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042



start_rpc: true

rpc_address: 0.0.0.0

rpc_port: 9160

broadcast_rpc_address: 10.140.0.2

rpc_keepalive: true

rpc_server_type: sync




thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15

incremental_backups: false

snapshot_before_compaction: false

auto_snapshot: true

tombstone_warn_threshold: 1000
tombstone_failure_threshold: 100000

column_index_size_in_kb: 64


batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb: 64

batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb: 640

unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold: 10


compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16

compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb: 100

sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb: 50



read_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 2000
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
request_timeout_in_ms: 10000

cross_node_timeout: false


phi_convict_threshold: 12

endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch

dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100 
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1

request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler



server_encryption_options:
    internode_encryption: none
    keystore: resources/dse/conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
    truststore: resources/dse/conf/.truststore
    truststore_password: cassandra
    # More advanced defaults below:
    # protocol: TLS
    # algorithm: SunX509
    # store_type: JKS
    # cipher_suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_
AES_256_CBC_SHA]
    # require_client_auth: false

client_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    # If enabled and optional is set to true encrypted and unencrypted connections are handled.
    optional: false
    keystore: resources/dse/conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
    # require_client_auth: false
    # Set trustore and truststore_password if require_client_auth is true
    # truststore: resources/dse/conf/.truststore
    # truststore_password: cassandra
    # More advanced defaults below:
    # protocol: TLS
    # algorithm: SunX509
    # store_type: JKS
    # cipher_suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_
AES_256_CBC_SHA]

internode_compression: dc

inter_dc_tcp_nodelay: false

tracetype_query_ttl: 86400
tracetype_repair_ttl: 604800

gc_warn_threshold_in_ms: 1000

enable_user_defined_functions: false

enable_scripted_user_defined_functions: false

windows_timer_interval: 1

auto_bootstrap: false
```

Thanks,

Comment: Java code you wrote, is needed to solve the issue. please post code. yaml file is most likely not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the table name it is trying to parse, you are likely using a version of the datastax java driver older than 3.0.   Cassandra 3.0 changes the way schema tables are parsed, so you need a version of the java-driver 3.0 or greater (3.1.1 is the latest).

Comment: Thanks. Issue is resolved by pointing correct version of Driver.